# NServiceBus invalid characters in header

Tags: nservicebus

We are using 3.2.2 of NServiceBus and in one of our environments the message headers are being generated with some odd characters appended to the end. The message is already showing up like this in the outgoing queue. We have 5 environments total (DEV, QA, STG, PROD, PLT) and it's working in all of them except one. It we strip the characters from the header and rerun the message all works fine.

Are these characters some sort of security hash or something similar? Any idea where they are being generated?

[image: Message header with odd characters appended]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deleting the app pool/app  and recreating the app pool / app fixed it for us. Sorry I don't know why it fixed the issue.